# SQL Result of Select with count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

this should be such an easy SQL Query but somehow I do struggle alot. No idea why...

I have two Tables (**USERINFO** and **FRIENDS**) and i want to get all Friends starting with 'm' for example and check if I am a friend of that.

The only Problem is, i want to check if the **USERID is in the second table** and i cant get it working. Tried using a join but didnt help very much...

My code so far:

```
SELECT u.USERID, u.USERNAME, u.USERPIC, f.ISFRIEND FROM 
                (SELECT * FROM USERINFO WHERE MATCH (USERNAME) AGAINST ('*m*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as u, 
                (SELECT count(*) as ISFRIEND FROM FRIENDS WHERE (User_ID = 2 AND Friend_ID = u.USERID) OR (User_ID = u.USERID AND Friend_ID = 2)) as f
```

u.USERID should be checked 'dynamically'

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

This code is *working obviously*, but i **need to check the ID I get from the select query before**...

```
SELECT u.USERID, u.USERNAME, u.USERPIC, f.ISFRIEND FROM 
                (SELECT * FROM USERINFO WHERE MATCH (USERNAME) AGAINST ('*m*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as u, 
                (SELECT count(*) as ISFRIEND FROM FRIENDS WHERE (User_ID = 2 AND Friend_ID = 1) OR (User_ID = 1 AND Friend_ID = 2)) as f
```

Thanks in advance :)

Markus

Comment: What do you mean you want to check if the UserId is in the second table?

Comment: Well my mobile App sends the UsersID to the SQL Query and i want to check if i am friends with that person.
So if i fetch all people starting with m, i want to check if i am friends with them.
Example the App users ID is 1 and one Person starting with 'm' like Markus, is my Friend (in Friends table) my output ISFRIEND should be 1. If not it should be 0

Comment: Then you don't go with count(*). I''l give you an answer in a few seconds.

Comment: Your Users table seems to have a many-to-many relationship with Friends which would not be ideal.

Comment: Hi what I don't get is whether your app sends one or 2 User's Id's and where the m for markus comes into play. Do you really want to get such a huge list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to get whether that person is a friend or not who starts with m.

Given that you didn't provide Details about your Data Structure we have to approach a result (will adjust if applicable).

```
SELECT
    u.USERID, u.USERNAME, u.USERPIC, 
    case
        when exists (SELECT 0 FROM FRIENDS WHERE (User_ID = 1 AND Friend_ID = u.USERID) OR (User_ID = u.USERID AND Friend_ID = 1)) then 1
        else 0
    end as ISFRIEND

FROM USERINFO u

WHERE MATCH (u.USERNAME) AGAINST ('*m*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This would not be performant in large systems since you always get a huge list of people starting with m* actually you compare with

```
*m*
```

which will give you all users who have got an m in their name. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Man, you saved my Day, this works flawless :)
The check for the m is just for debugging purposes :) 
I will limit 100 or so later and only starting with the 'm'.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something like the following. This will return all users with a name beginning with m, and join where their friend is the passed in user. If there is no join then this will indicate that the user is not a friend of the given user.

```
SELECT 
    u.USERID, 
    u.USERNAME, 
    u.USERPIC, 
    CASE WHEN f.User_ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END CASE AS ISFRIEND 
FROM USERINFO AS u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FRIENDS AS f ON f.User_ID = u.USERID AND f.User_ID = 46))
WHERE MATCH (u.USERNAME) AGAINST ('*m*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```